# inheritance and deque of objects in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, deque

I have multiple controls organized like this:

```
deque<wxTextCtrl*> dequeEdit;
deque<wxStaticText*> dequeText;
deque<wxComboBox*> dequeCombo;
```

All these controls inherit from wxWindow which has mathod Show. I'd like to show (or hide) whole deque at once, without the need of multiple methods for each deque. How could it be done?

I was thinking about making deque of wxWindow for each control, so I could write method

```
ShowDeque(deque<wxWindow*> deque)
```

so showing would be easy, but on the other hand, if I'd like to work with e.g. combobox, I'd have to type it back to wxComboBox. 
Are there any other possibilites? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
for_each(dequeEdit.begin(), dequeEdit.end(), mem_fun(&wxWindow::Show));
```

Same for any other deques.

Or encapsulate in one function:

```
template <class Deque>
void showAll(const Deque& dequeObj)
{
   using namespace std;
   for_each(dequeObj.begin(), dequeObj.end(), mem_fun(&wxWindow::Show));
}

showAll(dequeEdit);
```

1. `std::for_each`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each
2. `std::mem_fun`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn

Comment: Should be mem_fun not mem_fun_ref.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function template.

```
template <typename T>
void show_all(const std::deque<T*>& d) {
    for (typename std::deque<T*>::iterator it=d.begin(); it!=d.end(); ++it)
        (*it)->Show();
}
```

You can then call it like a normal function.

```
deque<wxTextCtrl*> dequeEdit;
deque<wxStaticText*> dequeText;
deque<wxComboBox*> dequeCombo;

show_all(dequeEdit);
show_all(dequeText);
show_all(dequeCombo);
```

With a function template you can even make `show_all` independent of the container you use by adding an additional template argument.

```
template <typename C, typename T>
void show_all(const C<T*>& d) {
    for (typename C<T*>::iterator it=d.begin(); it!=d.end(); ++it)
        (*it)->Show();
}
```

`C` can then be any STL container, or even any container which supports the same iterator interface.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple method make it a template:

```
template <typename WxT>
void ShowDeque(std::deque<WxT*> &d) { ... }
```

or better, use iterators to abstract out the container type:

```
template <typename WxIter>
void ShowDeque(WxIter begin, WxIter end) { ... }
```

or better yet use the standard facilities (Piotr beat me to that one while I was typing!)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when looking for how to use inheritance of iterators and deque.
The answer's does not give a complete answer related to inheritance, so I will add following:

Let say you have a class and you want this class to have the ability to have a deque inside, in other words to inherit the ability to control a deque container.

Example :

```
        template<typename ElementType>
        class myQueOfElements : public deque<ElementType>
        {
             ElementType placeholder;

             myQueOfElements& operator=(unsigned char* rvalue)
             {
                unsigned char* ptrToNextElement = (unsigned char*)rvalue;
                placeholder = ptrToNextElement;  // make sure ElementType has its own assignment operator=
                push_back(placeholder); // First element
            
                //TODO: Iterate thru the binary and push_back the fetched elements 

                return *this;
              }
        };
```

// How to use:

```
        myQueOfElements<myElementTypeClass> testQue;
        testQue = (unsigned char*)&blob[0];  // address to binary data, will be parsed in the assignment operator=
                                             // make sure it has same structure as the ElementType (myElementTypeClass) 

        // fetch all myElementTypeClass object(s) from the myQueOfElements 
        for (auto e : testQue) {
            std::string strName = e.Name;
            std::out << "Element : " << strName.c_str() << endl;
        }
```